# Echad Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred one?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(אסתר: ז. ו).

המלך והמלכה = 201

Answer (score 2):

201 is the minimum number of parts, one of which is *orla* or *kil'ay hakerem*, required to 'nullify' the *orla* or *kil'ay hakerem*. Source: [משנה ערלה ב א](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%91_%D7%90)‎.

Comment: do you have a source?

Comment: @Menachem, added.

Answer (score 0):

201 years from *Yaakov*'s birth to *Yosef*'s death. ([91 years to his birth](http://web.archive.org/web/20070816193605/www.math.wustl.edu/~msh210/torah_timeline.html) and [another 110 thereafter](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%A0_%D7%9B%D7%95).)